# Behavior of relations in EF Core, concurrency of when objects are created

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've come across a problem with Entity framework Core 2.0.2 and I wonder if someone can enlighten me.

What I have is a person class with a collection of phone numbers.

**Person**

```
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; } = new List<PhoneNumber>();
}
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
public class PhoneNumber : BaseEntity
{
    public string Usage { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

BaseEntity is basically just a property with an id.

Then I have a generic repo

**Repository**

```
public class Repository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly Dab2_2RdbContext _context;

    public Repository(Dab2_2RdbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Create(T t)
    {
        _context.Entry<T>(t).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T Read(int id)
    {
        return _context.Find<T>(id);
    }
    public void Update(int id, T t)
    {
        _context.Entry<T>(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void Delete(T t)
    {
        _context.Entry<T>(t).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

All of this code is very simple and works fine.
The situation happens when I test the code like this:

```
var context = new Dab2_2RdbContext();
var personRepo = new Repository<Person>(context);
var phoneNumberRepo = new Repository<PhoneNumber>(context);

var person = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "Kasper",
    LastName = "Lastname",
    Email = "Something@gmail.com",
    Context = "Myself",
};

person.PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>()
{
    new PhoneNumber() {Usage = "Work"},
    new PhoneNumber() {Usage = "School"}
};

// Create
personRepo.Create(person);
```

This code generates a person with proper values, however, it doesn't include the Phone numbers.

```
var context = new Dab2_2RdbContext();
var personRepo = new Repository<Person>(context);
var phoneNumberRepo = new Repository<PhoneNumber>(context);

var person = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "Kasper",
    LastName = "Lastname",
    Email = "Something@gmail.com",
    Context = "Myself",
};

// Create
personRepo.Create(person);

person.PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>()
{
    new PhoneNumber() {Usage = "Work"},
    new PhoneNumber() {Usage = "School"}
};
personRepo.Update(person.Id, person);
```

This code makes the proper relationship (the person.The phonenumber relation has been made. Notice the // Create person, shifted above person.Phone number

I wonder if someone can enlighten me, I really can figure out why this is.

Comment: Not sure where did you get that naïve "generic" code and why do you say "it works fine", while apparently it doesn't. For instance, in EF Core setting the entry state to `Added` is not the same as calling `Add` method (as it should). I would suggest you carefully reading [Disconnected entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities), [Basic Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic) and [Saving Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) sections of the documentation.

Comment: It was the add that was wrong, is it because it includes other non tracked properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that setting the state of the entry. Will only track the entity, and none of it's properties. While add will track all the navigation properties.